# How to Invoke JavaScript from Xamarin.Forms app without using Uno.UI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webassembly, uno-platform

I have a Xamarin.Forms app and it projected to WASM via [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/xamarin-forms/) . I need open a web link after click or tap. I solve it with:

```
 try // Uwp & iOS & Android
            {
                await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri("http://localhost"), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred); // Open url in-app browser for iOS & Android- native in UWP
            }
            catch (NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException ex) //Wasm falls here because lack of Xamarin.Essentials.
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Hata", "Not supported on WASM", "Anladım"); // Show the info about exception.



            }
```

for Xamarin. Android & iOS and UWP(Windows). However, the Xamarin.Essentials cannot run on WASM yet. So I need to invoke the Javascript and run this code:

```
function openPage(x) {
    window.open(x);
}
```

I try to use UNO.Foundation for

```
WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("(function(){location.href=\"https://www.wikipedia.com/\";})();");
```

However, it interfere with the UWP UI classes and brokes my project. How can I invoke Javascript from Xamarin.Forms page C# backend without using UNO.Foundation class ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hybrid webview then inject JavaScript code to detect every click on this web view 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview